# timer to send emails

Tags: email, workflow

can we create timer trigger to send email in standard objects and could customize time everytime the record created as in the fixed time based on the record type. Also, could we make the number of emails into limits such as 4 and one mail f24 hours ?

Comment: You can schedule emails using time dependent workflow actions (see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245) & [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US)), as long as your workflow criteria is set to 'Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria'. I'm not sure what you mean by 'making emails into limits' but you could add some criteria to the workflow rule to make sure that only 1 is sent per record per day / hour etc, if that's what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer. Here is what i am looking for. Once the case is created,  i want the system to send auto email to the case requester if there is no reponse in 24 hours after the response mail..it should send a mail time every 24 hours for three times.

Comment: Perfect, is there a field on the record that's changed when there is a response? (You'll need to reference this so that the email's aren't sent if a response is received).

Comment: but my requirement is for the system to send email if there is no response from the requester. there is no DML transaction with case record. however, it trigger the email for three times with interval of 24 hours....

Comment: I understand but obviously you don't want the email to be sent to the Case Requestor, even if they do respond. So when they respond is a field on the Case updated (the workflow rule will check this field and if it's changed to the 'responded' value, won't send any remaining scheduled emails).

Comment: sorry..but i want the email to be sent only if there is no response from the requester.  If the requester responded that will modifies the field in the case record. If not, it should send a mail something like remainder to response to our query and send it for certain number of times in order to have the case closed as no response.

Comment: Hopefully my question will make more sense once you read the documentation from the link in my Answer. It's slightly confusing at first!

Comment: last question. can we use Time-Based Workflow in all standard objects ?

Comment: No worries, yes & with custom objects too...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using code, workflow rules can be used to schedule automated email alerts, without the need for any user intervention once the workflow criteria have been met.

You'll need to create a workflow rule that's triggered when a field on the Case is changed, to indicate that the Case Requester has been sent an email (and the response from them is pending) - for example, the Case Status.

The rule criteria for this would be `Case: Status EQUALS Sent` but since you won't want the emails to be sent if the Case Requester responds, you'll also need to include `Case: Status NOT EQUAL TO Responded`, for example. Include both criteria in an `AND( *criteria* )` expression.

The workflow criteria must be set to 'Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria' so that a time dependent workflow can be used.

Then, before activating the workflow, add the time dependent workflow actions (email alerts) x days after rule trigger date, using your existing email alerts & templates. Then activate the workflow.

If you workflow criteria is no longer met - if the Case Status is changed to Responded in my example - then any remaining scheduled emails will not be sent. See this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245) for more details.